# Quickfix/J - Automatic re logon after Session disconnect("Done", false);

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I have a Quickfix/J implementation and when I call this:

```
// from the sender/initiator    
Session.lookupSession(sessionId).disconnect("Done", false);
```

I get the expected behaviour on the onLogout handlers

```
SenderFixEngine standalone logged off 
Receiver Fix Engine  logged OFF, next sender num : 2 next target num : 3
```

but I then immediately get the reverse happening automatically

```
Receiver Fix Engine logged ON  next sender num : 3 next target num : 4
SenderFixEngine standalone logged on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual QF app design is not run-and-done, but an app that stays on during the duration of a session.  Thus, if the session is broke for some reason, the engine immediately tries to reconnect so you don't miss anything.

If you really want to stop, you should call `Initiator.stop()`.  Or better yet, just have your app terminate itself.

I honestly don't see any good reason to call `disconnect()`.

Comment: Sessions are typically daily or sometimes weekly.

Comment: Like Frank says, daily or weekly.  Assuming you are a client, your counterparty will set the session.  You configure this on your side in your config file with StartTime/EndTime (and for weekly sessions, also use StartDay/EndDay).